# GKE cluster - kernel

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to select which kernel the GKE cluster nodes will be using? I have a dependent daemonset that requires a kernel that is currently not supported.

Currently, it creates the cluster with Ubuntu 5.4.0-1059-gke or 5.4.0-1063-gke
Need something lower.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find a node image that meet your kernel version requirement [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes/m85) and [launch](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-images) a cluster with it.

Comment: Thank you but, i'm using Ubuntu and not COS plus, the "--image-type" (by default it's COS) does let you choose "ubuntu" however, I cannot select the image that would have a specific kernel version.... perhaps i'm missing something.